# Unable to read text when using a dark theme

Tags: themes, text

Anytime I install a dark theme I am unable to read the text in the software center as well as many other applications because the text is white and the software center background is also white.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I know this problem and it is hard to describe. Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: And the name (and download link) of a dark theme that illustrates the issue so that others who don't know the problem can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

[image]**To install Delorean Dark theme in Ubuntu open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal-**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install delorean-dark
```

[image]**Delorean dark offers theme for software center enter these commands in terminal to get it:-**

```
cd /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/ && sudo mv softwarecenter.css softwarecenter.css.backup
cd /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/art/ && sudo mv stipple.png stipple.png.backup
cd && wget -O softwarecenter.css http://drive.noobslab.com/data/themes/delorean-dark-3.10/softwarecenter.css
sudo mv softwarecenter.css /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/`
cd && wget -O stipple.png http://drive.noobslab.com/data/themes/delorean-dark-3.10/stipple.png
sudo mv stipple.png /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/art/
```

To revert back software center theme simply enter these commands:

```
cd /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/ && sudo mv softwarecenter.css.backup softwarecenter.css
cd /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/art/ && sudo mv stipple.png.backup stipple.png
```

That's it.